# How to replace /update an array of objects with text box value within a check box check function - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

Check out this fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/shaswatatripathy/y7jqb5hp/1/).

So suppose you select two rows (by clicking check box )at first and add some text in text box then the array of objects will be having two objects with that property but second time he selects one row out of that two rows and deselect other one and give some value in  text box , we have to update the object with that in that array , currently its adding another object

Also , if he selects any other row , which `company` is not present in the array, its should add it as another object.

How to write that in that each checked function?

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>checkbox</th>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input name="eachRow" type="checkbox" /> </td>
    <td>Alfreds </td>
    <td>Maria </td>
    <td>Germany</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input name="eachRow" type="checkbox" /> </td>
    <td>Centro </td>
    <td>Francisco </td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input name="eachRow" type="checkbox" /> </td>
    <td>Ernst </td>
    <td>Roland </td>
    <td>Austria</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input name="eachRow" type="checkbox" /> </td>
    <td>Island </td>
    <td>Helen </td>
    <td>UK</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input name="eachRow" type="checkbox" /> </td>
    <td>Laughing  </td>
    <td>Yoshi </td>
    <td>Canada</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input name="eachRow" type="checkbox" /> </td>
    <td>Magazzini </td>
    <td>Giovanni </td>
    <td>Italy</td>
</tr>
```

CSS:

```
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

Jquery:

```
   var selectedRows = [];
    function getdetails() {
        var modifier = $('#txtBox').val();
        $.each($("input[name='eachRow']:checked").parents("tr"), function () {
            selectedRows.push({
                company: $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text(),
                contact: modifier
            });
            console.log(selectedRows);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code is doing exactly what it suppose to, each time you click on the button, the method pushes into array all the checked objects. if you do:

```
function getdetails() {
    var selectedRows = [];
    var modifier = $('#txtBox').val();
    $.each($("input[name='eachRow']:checked").parents("tr"), function () {
        selectedRows.push({
            company: $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text(),
            contact: modifier
        });
    });
    console.log(selectedRows);
}
```

(adding selected rows initialization inside function) you'll get what you want: a new calculation each time. If what you want is update elements on each click of the button, well then you need different methods